# Finding significance and power of test from example

Tags: statistics

For a problem given the following information below, I am not sure how to find the significance $\alpha$ and power ($1-\beta$) of the test

> sample size, n=10 and assuming iid $X_i ,i=1,...,10$ is N(0,$\sigma ^2$) with $H_0: \sigma ^2=5, vs,H_1: \sigma ^2=8$ with statistic $T=T(X_i)$ that is positive and critical region T$\ge50$

I am assuming that you aren't suppose to just choose a significance level(e.g $\alpha=0.05$) and that you need to use $\alpha$ to then find the power of the test. Could anyone give me a hint on how I need to find $\alpha$? I am guessing that I can get $\alpha$ from the critial region but not sure how:

$2P(T\ge 50)=\alpha$

as the hypothesis is a two sided etc $H_0: \sigma ^2=5, vs,H_1: \sigma ^2\neq 5$

Comment: Did you find a suitable test statistic $T$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Yes, it involves the summation of all X_i terms. How would I use that information to find alpha? I don't want to write down that T(X_i) is specifically as this is an assignment problem, but what would the general idea be if I knew it and then used to find alpha?

Comment: Since you are given the critical region $T\ge 50$, level of the test is $P_{H_0}(T\ge 50)$. This is not a 'two-sided' hypothesis.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Ok say T(Xi) =$\sum_{i=1}^{5} X_i$, then $P_{H0}(\sum_{i=1}^{5} X_i≥50)$, I then don't know how to simplify things. What might I need to try doing then?

Comment: To clarify, your test statistic should ideally be a function of a sufficient statistic, in this case $\sum X_i^2$. So if $T=\sum X_i^2$, then you have $T/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_{10}$, from which you can find the required probability under $H_0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom , So with the chi square df=10, I find a p value =  2.669083e-07 with calculator then P(T>=50)=2.669083e-07 = alpha my significance level? Shouldn't it also be 9 df?

Comment: You are not estimating the mean. So why should it be 9 df?